# MDX distinctcount conditional calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm really new in MDX and having trouble calculating results. I'm working with SSAS 2012 and designing my cube in Visual Studio. This is my current query:

```
WITH MEMBER [DocCount] AS
  IIF(([Measures].[Responsible Count] > 0 AND [Measures].[Responsible2 Count] > 0),
       [Measures].[DocName]*0.5, [Measures].[DocName]) 

SELECT {[DocCount]} ON 0, [Analysis Table].[Responsible].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [database]
```

SQL table is this

```
ID    DocName    Responsible   Responsible2
1     100001     John Doe      Mary Jane
2     100001     Mary Jane     John Doe
3     100002     Mike Doe      NULL
4     100003     John Doe      Mike Doe
5     100003     John Doe      Mike Doe
6     100004     Mary Jane     NULL

[Measures].[Responsible Count] is "count of non-empty values" selection in VS
[Measures].[Responsible2 Count] is "count of non-empty values" selection in VS
[Measures].[DocName] is "distinct count" selection in VS
```

I need to calculate DISTINCTCOUNT DocName, but when Responsible AND Responsible2 is not null, Count should be *0.5. The problem is that Cube data is aggregated and only then my [DocCount] IIF is evaluated. Current results are like this:

```
Responsible    DocCount
John Doe       1        --(2*0.5) because it distinct counts DocName and then *0.5 it
Mary Jane      1        -- (2*0.5) it does not care that ID 6 responsible2 is null
Mike Doe       1        -- (1) this is correct
```

I want this Final result:

```
Responsible    DocCount
John Doe       1           --(0.5+0.5)  ID 1,2 and 4,5
Mary Jane      1.5         --(0.5 + 1)  ID 1,2 and 6
Mike Doe       1           --(1 )       ID 3
```

how to modify my query for it to calculate correct results ?

Comment: So your `[Analysis Table]` is a dimension in Analysis Services with attributes `ID`, `DocName`, `Responsible`, and `Responsible2`?

Comment: I would say your query is nearly correct. Probably the main problem is with the definition of the measures used ([Measures].[Responsible Count], [Measures].[Responsible2 Count],  [Measures].[DocName]). Could you edit your question to include their definition?

Comment: I edited my question. [Analysis Table] has attributes ID, DocName and Responsible. Responsible2 is not needed as attribute. Currently it is only a measure.

Comment: How should the result be if there would be a record with DocName 100001, Responsible "Mary Jane", and Responsible2 NULL? Would the `* 0.5` or the `* 1` rule have precedence for her?

Comment: the point here is simple: If two responsible persons are working on the same DocName, then it should be divided in half (hence *0.5). If only one person is working on a document (responsible2 is null) then it should not be divided (hence *1). In your mentioned example this could not happen, because document is either created by 2 persons (no matter how many rows the same DocName has), or it is created by one person (also does not matter how many rows). I hope this would be a bit clearer what I'm trying to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made solution myself. I replaced my fact table with named query where I added additional column which will find only distinct rows by DocName and evaluate if that row has both Responsible and Responsible2 not null. If yes - it will enter 0.5, else - 1. Then it was plain simple to add Measure out of this column and test my results.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this would be to model this correctly:

Define a "Responsible" dimension containing one entry for each person appearing either in the Responsible or in the Responsible2 column, and a "Document" dimension table containing one row per distinct document. Each of these dimension tables should also have a numeric primary key column, and may have additional columns for other properties of the person (maybe department, gender, ...) or document (maybe name, path in file system, creation date, number of pages, ...).

Then you would have a fact table which has three columns: two foreign key columns referencing the primary keys of the dimension tables, and a measure column, maybe called `DocCount`, which would be  `1 / number of authors referenced by the document id` (i. e. 1 for one author, and 0.5 for two authors).

Then all you would have to do is to set up the cube based on this. You would not need any complex MDX calculations, everything would be handled by Analysis Services based on the cube structure. This would also allow to use any number of responsible persons and not just one or two for a document.

It would be possible to solve your request in MDX with your design, but that would require some slightly complex MDX.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need a bit more clear description of what to do. I understood your answer suggests to create 2 named queries in DSV "Responsible" and "Document", where in "Responsible" it should be like this: select distinct(Responsible) from [Analysis Table] and in "Document" it should be: select distinct(DocName) from [Analysis Table]. Then create dimentions out of these. and then ?

Comment: @pirmasnaujas I extended my answer to explain the table structure more clearly.

Comment: thanks for you support @FrankPI. As I cannot remove or modify my current fact table, I created Named Query which lists distinct DocName and finds how many persons are working on the document: `SELECT distinct(DocName), case when responsible is not null and responsible2 is not null then 0.5 else 1 end as Responsible FROM [Analysis Table]`. So this **named query** seems to be my second fact table. I connected both fact tables with DocName, created new measure from **named query** fact table but in the report it just displays SUM of all rows. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: @pirmasnaujas How dis you define the new measure? As sum of the calculated column? Do you have a reference from the Responsible dimension to the new fact table? is it configured to be regular? Do you have this dimension in your query?